# Kibana main dashboard exception using logstash 1.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I previously had logstash 1.3.2 (& 1.3.1) running on ubuntu 12 - I was using the elasticsearch included with the jar file (not running it separately for testing purposes).  I just switched to logstash 1.3.3.  Now, when I launch kibana logstash dashboard, I receive the error copied below.  I am using collectd to gather the logs.

```
Oops! SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]
```

I have reduced the logstash conf file to this for testing:

```
input {
  stdin {
    type => "stdin-type"
  }

  collectd {}
}

output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch { embedded => true  } 
}
```

Any insight on how to debug this issue will be appreciated.  Currently, I am trying to focus on the data being sent to elasticsearch from collectd.  Thanks.

**Update**:
I tried reverting to 1.3.2 but still see the same issue.  I am inclined on removing the elasticsearch files from the data directory and try again.

Comment: Not sure what the issue was - I replaced the elasticsearch indices and was able to restart the logstash/elasticsearch/kibana processes without any issue.

Comment: I did modify sysctl for number of files but I do not recall that resolving the issue.